# Keeping ssh-connections while switching between different networks

Tags: networking, ssh

I am frequently switching between wireless and wired networks. Each time, all my ssh-connexions need to be closed and reissued. Is there some way to keep such connections open?

The only possibility I am aware of is to use screen. That is, to start a new connection and say

```
exec screen -r -d
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure of a way to do it natively, <strike>and I don't think screen would help as the server it is on is switching interfaces</strike> [here](http://pissedoffadmins.com/os/using-ssh-and-screen-to-create-persistent-terminal-sessions-accessible-from-almost-anywhere.html) is a blog post describing a work flow with intermittent ssh and screen. There is also [mosh](https://mosh.org/) which allows roaming shells.

Comment: If you can, it's better to write the answer here rather than providing just a link.